# modify the mobile portrait mode background video into browser support with aspect ratio responsively

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming, html5-video

how can be modify the portrait mode of background video support responsively covered with browser?

*I try to work like this, but that not supported that was fully covered*

```
        position: absolute;
        object-fit: cover; //also try fill method also but not worked
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: -1;
```

*i want like this*
[image]

Kindly help this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: -1;
min-height:100vh;
min-width:100vw;
object-fit:cover;
```

Comment: Hi @Lukas, thank for your answer. Unfortunately it was flagged as low quality because of its length. Could you add a sentence or two of explanation of how this works and why?

Comment: min-height sets minimal height to it can't be smaller than min-height value. It's the only way to force full height. vh - *relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*,  vw - *relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*.